# Ruby on rails edit form's select field does not populate saved value. What can i do?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I have a model which has column => gender:string.
When i open edit form, initial gender value does not populate true. Form always populate with first value.
What can i do to solve this?
By the way I'am trying to save same value as gender label.

```
<%= form.select :gender, options_for_select([['Erkek', 'erkek'], ['Kadın', 'kadın']]) %>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this will do

```
<%= form.select :gender, options_for_select([['Erkek', 'erkek'], ['Kadın', 'kadın']], form.object.gender), { include_blank: true } %>
```

> second argument to `options_for_select` is the selected value - `form.object.gender`
>
> `include_blank: true` is to add an empty option at the top

`[['Erkek', 'erkek']]` - in this array **Erkek** is label and **erkek** is the value

to save same value as as label then use a flat array. `['Erkek', 'Kadın']`

if your options are simple, you can use

```
<%= form.select :gender, [['Erkek', 'erkek'], ['Kadın', 'kadın']], { include_blank: true } %>
```

[select](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/select)

[options_for_select](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/options_for_select)